# Specifying --build-args inside a DockerFile's FROM

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My `DockerFile`:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow

...

# rest of file
```

Looking at the source `DockerFile` of `puckel/docker-airflow`, I see there are several `args` that can be configured at build time, which I want to do:

```
# contents of puckel/docker-airflow

...

# Airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.6
ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_DEPS=""
ARG PYTHON_DEPS=""
```

I know I can set these args using `docker build` and adding the flag(s), for example `docker build --build-arg AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.11 ...` for example, but how can I set these args within my `DockerFile` itself?

Comment: You did set it in your Dockerfile, e.g. `AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.6`

Comment: No, that's the contents of the DockerFile that I'm `FROM`ing from. I want to know how to change the AIRFLOW_VERSION when I pull it using `FROM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. When you build `FROM` another image, you are building from the result of a previous build. The parent image has already been created, and the `ARG`s have already been used. You have to rebuild the parent image with different args if you want changes applied there.

Note that build args are scoped, they only exist within the build stage (or Dockerfile for global args), and are not directly available to be used in child images.